# Modal dialog does not return focus to application

Tags: delphi, vcl, graphics32

I have a custom control derived from `TPanel` named `TTestCtrl`. It holds a `TImage32` (from Graphics32).

When the user double clicks on the image, I show a message. The problem is that after I close the message, the focus is not returned back to the main application. So, the first click, no matter what I click on in the main app/main form, is lost.

Strange thing: If I call the `Mesaj()` procedure not from the `TTestCtrl` but from the main form, it works (the first click is not lost anymore):

```
unit DerivedControl;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.Forms, GR32, GR32_Image;

type
  TTestCtrl = class(TPanel)
  private
    Img: TImage32;
  protected
    procedure ChromaDblClick(Sender: TObject);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  published
  end;

procedure Mesaj(const MessageText, Title: string);

implementation

procedure Mesaj(const MessageText, Title: string);
begin
{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
   Application.MessageBox(PChar(MessageText), PChar(Title), 0)  { 'Title' will appear in window's caption }
{$ELSE}
   MessageDlg(MessageText, mtInformation, [mbOk], 0);
{$ENDIF}
end;

constructor TTestCtrl.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  Width         := 200;
  Height        := 86;
  Img := TImage32.Create(Self);
  Img.Parent        := Self;
  Img.Align         := alClient;
  Img.OnDblClick    := ChromaDblClick;
end;

procedure TTestCtrl.ChromaDblClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Mesaj('Caption', 'From derived control');      // focus lost
end;

end.
```

---

The simple/minimal application below is the tester:

```
unit TesterForm;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Samples.Spin, Vcl.Controls, vcl.Forms, DerivedControl;

type
  TfrmTester = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
  public
  end;

var
  frmTester: TfrmTester;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

var
  Ctrl: TTestCtrl;

procedure TfrmTester.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Ctrl := TTestCtrl.Create(Self);
  Ctrl.Parent := Self;
end;

procedure TfrmTester.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Mesaj('Caption', 'From main form');      // works
end;

end.
```

Comment: Give focus to the form before launching the dialog. Or debug TImage32.

Comment: @Silvester - I meant before. But  you can try otherwise... The form that your control is parented with. You can use Parent or GetParentForm or similar.

Comment: Important note: I used the word 'focus' but I don't know if it is the correct word. The main form doesn't seem to be lost focus (to be a background window). It will just ignores the first click.

Comment: I have gr32 but I don't have a complete program. I'd have to work to build one. [mcve]

Comment: Please read this [mcve]

Comment: Silvester, the page linked by @David does not mention it but off-site downloads are not regarded. I'm not exactly sure what was wrong about your previous case. Maybe it failed to compile, or maybe you should have consolidated all into a unit. ...

Comment: I duplicated this with your previous revision. My suggestion is to not to launch a dialog on an image32 with a double click. Mouse handling in gr32 is quite complicated.

Comment: BTW you don't need a task dialog to observe the problem, message box is fine. Try to minimize the code required to duplicate the problem when preparing a mcve.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz-Thanks. Got it.

Comment: Good news: Graphics32 has been updated last month (04.2017)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
procedure TTestCtrl.ChromaDblClick(Sender: TObject);
var F : TcustomForm;
begin
  Mesaj('Caption', 'From derived control');      // focus lost
  F := GetParentForm(Self);
  if Assigned(F) then F.BringToFront;

end;
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this Monday.

Comment: @Silvester did you test this? Did it work if you did?

Comment: @Christophe - Ok then, thanks. This was one of the first things which I tested and did not help, with XE2. That's why I asked. The only workaround I could find was to post mouse messages which I didn't like. This is better of course, as long as it works.

Comment: you can also use Windows API functions :SetForegroundWindow, SetActiveWindow and FlashWindow to achieve something more

Comment: Nope. The window is already in the foreground and already has the focus.